# NSPopupButton in an NSTableCellView View causing a leak

Tags: swift, cocoa, memory-leaks, swift4, appkit

## *Environment*

- Xcode: 9.4.1
- Swift: 4
- Target Platform: 10.11

## *Problem*

I have these ridiculously simplistic NSViewController and NSTableViewCell subclasses that when combined give me very peculiar memory leaks (as reported by both the **Debug Memory Graph** and the **Memory Leak Instrument**) when I include a stock NSPopupButton in the SensorListCellView.

## *Code Stubs*

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableSensors: NSTableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let result:SensorListCellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "defaultRow"), owner: self) as! SensorListCellView

        // Just fill with any data
        result.imageSensorAvailable.image       = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("NSStatusAvailable"))
        result.imageSensorAvailable.toolTip     = "Sensor is Available & Reporting"
        result.sensorID.stringValue             = "Sensor ID"
        result.sensorDescription.stringValue    = "Sensor Description"
        result.sensorName.stringValue           = "Sensor Name"

        // Just fill with any data
        result.unitsAvailable.addItem(withTitle: "One")
        result.unitsAvailable.addItem(withTitle: "Two")
        result.unitsAvailable.addItem(withTitle: "Three")

        return result
    }
}

class SensorListCellView: NSTableCellView {
    @IBOutlet weak var unitLabel: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageSensorAvailable: NSImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorID: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorDescription: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sensorName: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var unitsAvailable: NSPopUpButton!
}
```

## *What's going on*

I get four leaks as seen in the [Debug Memory Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFDMz.png).  [Here is my very simple storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shPRC.jpg).
The description for all of the leaked CFDictionary objects is:

```
Printing description of $0:
{
    kCUIMeasureEdgeInsetBottomLeft = "NSSize: {9, 3}";
    kCUIMeasureEdgeInsetTopRight = "NSSize: {8, 6}";
    "measure.height" = 20;
    "measure.width" = 24;
}
```

If I remove the NSPopupButton, the memory leak goes away.  To say that I am at a loss is an understatement.  No matter what I do to the NSPopupButton, I get the four leaks with the description from above.

Any help, advice, or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get 4 leaks for each row? What are the constraints for the popup button? What is the Buildtime issue?

Comment: Let's see: No - just the four leaks regardless of the row count.  There are no constraints for any of the elements in the row, the TableCellView or the TableView itself.  it's just strange: I remove the PopupButton and it goes away.  This issue does not manifest with a ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 9.4.1, Swift 4, I was unable to find an answer other than "It was AppKit" itself that was leaking.  As of Xcode 10.0 - Beta 2, the behavior noted above is no longer being observed.  I consider the matter resolved.